# Which is best option to store binary image and search : Elastic search (ES) alone or Binary file storage system with ES

Tags: reactjs, image, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, storage

Which is best option to store binary image and search : Direct Image search using Elastic search (ES) or Image catalogue search using  Binary file storage system +ES ?

Is Elasticsearch data type binary is best used to store and search  user profile images than implementing using separate AWS s3 binary storage system  to store image and search by elastic search ?

which is faster and simplicit(.,operation difficulty) . ?

What will be the mapping and DSL query structure example  for creating a organisation employee profile user

1. with maximum upload of 3 photo limit with
2. image size 0.5Mb and
3. x height , y width